# Diagonal difference use Java 7 in Hackerrank

Tags: java, algorithm

I am new on hackerrank to solve this algorithm problem [Diagonal difference](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem) , I've come up with the solution but it shows runtime error, can anyone tell which part I wrote is wrong, thanks.

```
 /*
 * Complete the diagonalDifference function below.
 */
static int diagonalDifference(int[][] a) {
    /*
     * Write your code here.
     */
    int sum1=0;
    int sum2=0;
    int n = a[0].length;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    sum1 += a[i][i];
    sum2 += a[n-i][i];
    }
    return Math.abs(sum1-sum2);
}
```

Comment: While calculating sum2, You are trying to access an index `> n-1` when `i=0` . So change it to `sum2 += a[n-i-1][i]`;

Comment: you are right, I missed to minus 1, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line: `sum2 += a[n-i][i];`

For `i=0` it will be `a[n][0]` and index lies between `0 to n-1`; thus will lead to runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question,
`sum2 += a[n-i][i];` in here i = 0; so you are trying to access an index which is not in the array. it should be `sum2 += a[n-i-1][i]`

Here's how I did it in java 8. You'll be able to understand it and very similar to java 7.

```
    static int diagonalDifference(int[][] a, int n) {
        //I just edited this method
        int x=0, y=0,z,h=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            x = x + a[i][i];
        }
        for(int j = n-1; j >= 0; j-- ){
            y = y + a[h][j];
            h++;
        }
        //System.out.println(x);
        //System.out.println(y);
        if(x>y){
            z=x-y;
        }else{
            z=y-x;
        }
        return(z);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace sum2 += a[n-i][i] with sum2 += a[n-i-1][i].It will solve your problem.

For a detailed explanation, you can check out the below link-

https://youtu.be/f6bTIsj9ne8

There are a lot of sites and git hub repositories where you can find hackerRank solutions for most of the problems.

But I would recommend https://github.com/Java-aid/Hack... which is maintained by me. Here I may be biased but the trust me, you will find this repository useful.

In this repository, I am adding video tutorial too which you will not find in any of the git-hub repositories out there over the internet.

Here is the sample tutorial - https://youtu.be/gDltV7pJw7A

which will teach you amazing approaches to solve hackerrank staircase problem. Please watch the complete tutorial to know a tricky method to solve this problem.

Here my goal is not only to provide the solution but to build the problem-solving skills. Would recommend you to go through the video tutorials which will increase your logical ability.

Don't forget to share your feedback with others, if you like my work. :)